# DBeaver - External Formatter pgformatter

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver, formatter

Can someone help me with the step by step to install an External Formatter in DBeaver? Specifically pg-formatter.

I like to work with DBeaver for SQL queries, however, I don't like the formatting options that DBeaver comes with by default.

I have found this formatter on the web, but have not been able to install it. I would be very grateful if you could help me with the step-by-step.

https://github.com/gajus/pg-formatter

I have followed the steps described here in this link. But I still can't install it. Maybe I don't understand this step-by-step, because I'm not much of a command-line user.

https://github.com/darold/pgFormatter

Comment: Use the online version [pgFormatter](https://sqlformat.darold.net/).

Comment: see if you can follow https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/9733

Comment: @nbk Yes, the step by step appears and they are these:
**But I would like you to expand on step 1:
How to do the installation?**

**1. Install the formatter**
2. Open DBeaver>Editors>SQL Editor>SQL Formatting
3. Select Sql workbench/j formatter
4. Enter path to Sql workbench/j formatter
5. Apply the changes
6. Open SQL Editor
7. Enter SQL Expression
8. Press Ctrl+Shift+F (or select Format>Format SQL in DQL Editor context menu)

Comment: when you get it to work answer your own question and accept it, so that others can follow the steps too

Answer (score 0):

The pg_formatter is a perl app, so you need to have perl installed on your system.   Now assuming you've unzipped the formatter into a folder "E:\apps\pgFormatter-5.5" , set the dBeaver formatter to 'External' and in the command line box put:

```
perl.exe E:\apps\pgFormatter-5.5\pg_format -c E:\apps\pgFormatter-5.5\.pg_format.conf -
```

pg_format is the perl script and the .pg_format.conf is where you can adjust your formatting preferences (only required if you want non-default settings).  The " - " at the end means that it is reading from STDIN.